# 2D array view: range-based for loop iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I'm working with audio which has a lot of two dimensional sound buffers passed around like this:

```
(float**, int numChannels, int numSamples)
```

I'm looking to implement a quick array_ref style view (quick, non-owning, traversable view, knows its dimensions), but which allows me to do range-based `for` loops like this:

```
BufferView& buff {someRawBuffer, 2, 256};

for (auto chan : buff)
    for (auto samp : chan)
        samp *= 0.25f;
```

So far I have this, which is far from STL-complete (not what I'm aiming for, readability and brevity are priorities over generality, and I'm looking to learn). It seems to work, but a bit of a mess!

```
//==============================================================================

class SampleIterator
{
public:
    SampleIterator (float* sample, int numSamples)
        : fp {sample}, curr {sample}, samps {numSamples}
    {}

    float* operator++() { curr++; return curr; }
    float operator*()  { return *curr; }
    bool operator!= (const SampleIterator& other) { return curr != other.curr; }

    float* begin() { return &fp[0]; }
    float* end()   { return &fp[samps]; }

private:
    float* fp;
    float* curr;
    int samps;
};

//==============================================================================

class ChannelIterator
{
public:
    ChannelIterator (float** channel, int numSamples)
        : fpp {channel}, curr {channel}, samps {numSamples}
    {}

    float** operator++() { curr++; return curr; }
    SampleIterator operator*()  { return SampleIterator {*curr, samps}; }
    bool operator!= (const ChannelIterator& other) { return curr != other.curr; }

private:
    float** fpp;
    float** curr;
    int samps;
};

//==============================================================================

class BufferView
{
public:
    BufferView (float** buffer, int numChannels, int numSamples)
        : fpp {buffer}, chans {numChannels}, samps {numSamples}
    {
    }

          float& operator() (int chan, int samp)       { return fpp[chan][samp]; } // debugmode range check?
    const float& operator() (int chan, int samp) const { return fpp[chan][samp]; }

    ChannelIterator begin() { return ChannelIterator {&fpp[0],     samps}; } // const versions?
    ChannelIterator end()   { return ChannelIterator {&fpp[chans], samps}; }

private:
    float** fpp;
    int chans;
    int samps;
};
```

And the (non-real world) usage sketch is here:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    float chan1[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    float chan2[4] = {5, 6, 7, 8};
    float* rawbuf[2] = {chan1, chan2};

    for (int chan = 0; chan < 2; ++chan)
        for (int samp = 0; samp < 4; ++samp)
            std::cout << rawbuf[chan][samp] << "\n";

    BufferView bv {buf, 2, 4};

    for (int chan = 0; chan < 2; ++chan)
        for (int samp = 0; samp < 4; ++samp)
            std::cout << bv(chan,samp) << "\n";

    // this is the usage I'm looking for...

    for (auto chan : bv)
        for (auto samp : chan)
            std::cout << "range for loop " << samp << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

My main concerns are:

- Where should I be putting the iterators?
- There seems to be redundant code? (e.g. data members are same in some cases)
- Do I need to pass `samps` (size of 2nd dimension) all the way down through the iterators?
- Any other way I can be reducing the design to get simple range-based for loop traversal?

I'll gladly discuss the BufferView in general after I've tidied the iterators!

**EDIT: Some improvements...**

Okay so I've improved the code a little which seems much more structured to me...

```
//==============================================================================

class ChannelView
{
public:
    ChannelView (float* buffer, int numSamples)
        : fp {buffer}, samps {numSamples}
    {}

          float& operator() (int samp)       { return fp[samp]; }                   // debugmode range check?
    const float& operator() (int samp) const { return fp[samp]; }

    //==============================================================================

    class SampleIterator
    {
    public:
        SampleIterator (float* sample)
            : curr {sample}
        {}

        float* operator++() { curr++; return curr; }
        float operator*() { return *curr; }
        bool operator!= (const SampleIterator& other) { return curr != other.curr; }

    private:
        float* curr;
    };

    SampleIterator begin() { return SampleIterator {&fp[0]    }; }                  // const versions?
    SampleIterator end()   { return SampleIterator {&fp[samps]}; }

private:
    float* fp;
    int samps;
};

//==============================================================================

class BufferView
{
public:
    BufferView (float** buffer, int numChannels, int numSamples)
        : fpp {buffer}, chans {numChannels}, samps {numSamples}
    {}                                                                              //gsl::Expects

          float& operator() (int chan, int samp)       { return fpp[chan][samp]; }  // debugmode range check?
    const float& operator() (int chan, int samp) const { return fpp[chan][samp]; }

    //==============================================================================

    class ChannelIterator
    {
    public:
        ChannelIterator (float** channel, int numSamples)
            : curr {channel}, samps {numSamples}
        {}

        float** operator++() { curr++; return curr; }
        ChannelView operator*() { return ChannelView {*curr, samps}; }
        bool operator!= (const ChannelIterator& other) { return curr != other.curr; }

    private:
        float** curr;
        int samps;
    };

    ChannelIterator begin() { return ChannelIterator {&fpp[0],     samps}; }    // const versions?
    ChannelIterator end()   { return ChannelIterator {&fpp[chans], samps}; }

private:
    float** fpp;
    int chans;
    int samps;
};

//==============================================================================

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    float chan1[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    float chan2[4] = {5, 6, 7, 8};
    float* buf[2] = {chan1, chan2};

    BufferView bv {buf, 2, 4};

    for (auto chan : bv)
        for (auto samp : chan)
            std::cout << "range for loop " << samp << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Main changes:

- Implemented a `ChannelView` which is the next level down hierarchically to `BufferView`.
- Nested the `Iterator` classes appropriately
- Dereference operator in `ChannelIterator` returns a `ChannelView` like this `ChannelView operator*() { return ChannelView {*curr, samps}; }`

What still looks unorthodox to me is that `samps` (number of samples per channel) is also stored in the `ChannelIterator` (in order to instantiate the `ChannelView` on dereference. `ChannelView` needs to know its size).

It's better than before where `samps` was passed all the way down 2 classes.

The only other way I could think is if on construction of `BufferView` we construct and hold a `ChannelView` member per channel. But that seems like a case of paying-for-what-you-don't-use, if you never need to iterate. So creating a `ChannelView` only on dereference seems preferable?..

```
ChannelView operator*() { return ChannelView {*curr, samps}; }
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated?!

Comment: In what form comes input? Vector, array, C array? If it is the same as in the function declaration you could replace it with `std::vector<const std::vector<float>>` and it will have roughly the same memory layout and will have iterators out of the box.

Comment: @Incomputable The input comes from various libraries with mostly C-style `(float** data, int n_chans, int n_samps)` (I don't have control over this). So I'm trying to implement a simple non-owning view (similar to `GSL::span`) which I can quickly/cheaply wrap legacy code. I did think of `vector<vector>`but that would own data/a copy of the data.

Comment: Should iterator types of outer loop and inner match? It is possible to do with some template metaprogramming, but it will complicate things a bit.

Comment: @Incomputable To give more info, I have to interface with a lot of different library code, all using various representations of a buffer of sound (but nearly all can be manipulated into `(float** data, int n_chans, int n_samps)` form). Also in a real time DSP loop, you don't want to copy data, you just want to manipulate the data where it is (hence a non-owning view seems to be a solution?)

Comment: @Incomputable Replied at the same time! I don't think they should match because, when dereferenced, an iterator over an audio buffer should return a channel of float samples. Whereas an iterator over a buffer channel should return a single float sample when dereferenced. (I stand to be corrected!)

Comment: I can write recursive iterator where at last level of recursion it will return T. I need some time to test it though, I'll post it here as a question if I'll be able to make it work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53115/discussion-between-incomputable-and-ternonlerwen).

Answer (score 2):

**Good already:**

The code should be good enough for the most usage cases. There are some small nitpicks that could be found, but I believe they are constraints of the API used.

- const versions of the member functions can be added

**Recursive iterators:**

So I had an idea to create recursive iterators but run into a problem after some time. The problem is that complexity escalates [way too fast](https://gist.github.com/simmplecoder/9d6a67a4573dc5c8e0888466a948d34b). Implementation also requires keeping the dimensions of all lower indirections, which probably violates *don't pay for what you don't use* idiom.

**Generic solution:**

Despite it is hard to write recursive iterator, it is quite possible to write two level iterator. It can be achieved by simply creating a template and specializing it for the first and second level of indirection. The latter will return `recursive_iterator<T*>`, whereas itself will be `recursive_iterator<T**>`. It should be easily achievable since the code already uses the same idea.